# Looping & If not working for the second instruction

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

I'm relatively new in Excel VBA and what i'm doing is a loader for one of our ERPs. So my problem is this...I have an excel worksheet, let's call it the origin and another one, let's call it dummy.

What i want to do is for the macro to check if a certain cell (af18) in origin range falls into criteria. If its true, then copy a A18 from origin sheet to dummy sheet. Then insert "{tab} on the next column. then if AF19 (the next cell) falls into the criteria, copy the a19 to dummy's next blank column then again insert {tab}.

The current code produces this: `1,2,3...\{tab}`

But I want it to be like this: `1,\{tab},2,\{tab}...`

[image]

```
  Sub CreateLoaderBeta()

  Dim origin As Worksheet
  Dim destination As Worksheet
  Dim desrow As Long
  Dim descol As Long
  Dim descolstart As Long
  Dim origrow As Long
  Dim origcol As Long
  Dim rang As Range
  Dim C As Range
  Dim qual As Integer

  Set origin = Sheets("1")
  Set destination = Sheets("dummy")
  desrow = 3
  descol = 1
  origrow = 18
  origcol = 32
  Set rng = Sheets("1").Range("AF18:af47")
  total = WorksheetFunction.SUM(Worksheets("1").Range("AF18:AF47"))
  descolstart = destination.cells(desrow, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).column

  If total > 0 Then

    'Dim headcol As Integer
    'headcol = 1

    'origin.cells(3, headcol).Copy
    'destination.cells(1, descolstart).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues


    For Each C In rng
        If C = 14 Then
                origin.cells(origrow, 1).Copy
                destination.cells(1, descolstart).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
                destination.cells(1, descolstart + 1).Value = "\{TAB}"
                descolstart = descolstart + 1
                origrow = origrow + 1
        End If
    Next C

    destination.Columns("A:U").insert Shift:=xlToRight
    Call headers


    Else 'Donothing


    End If

    MsgBox total

    End Sub**
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> destination.cells(1, descolstart).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
> destination.cells(1, descolstart + 1).Value = "\{TAB}"
> descolstart = descolstart + 1
> ```

You are overwriting the `"\{TAB}"` you just wrote, in the next iteration. The `descolstart` must be incremented by `2` at each iteration because each iteration consumes two columns.

```
descolstart = descolstart + 2  ' <------------ +2, not +1
```

Comment: Thank you so much.  :) That's exactly what I'm missing.

Comment: _"Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score."_ I think am not yet allowed to do that. :( Sad.

Comment: @LiezlMaigue: Taken care of ;)

Comment: @SiddharthRout lol, thanks, could you accept the answer while at it? :P

Comment: Wish I could :)

Comment: Done @A.S.H. :)